# Possible Xamp or script error?

Tags: php, xampp, server

First time uploading image and getting this error. Image is **.jpg**. Script seems to be OK for me. So I think problem is with **xamp server?**

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB42E.tmp' is not a
valid PNG file in C:\xampp\htdocs\phphph\check_image.php on line 66
The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype
```

I was searching on google and didnt find something usefull. So here is part of the script.

```
 switch ($type){
   case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']) or 
        die ('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
        $ext = ' .gif';
        break;
   case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']) or 
        die ('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
        $ext = ' .jpeg';
   case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']) or 
        die ('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
        $ext = ' .png';
        break;
    default:
        die('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype.');              
   }
```

Comment: How do you determine `$type`?

Comment: @briansol for now it is set by browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `break`:

```
    $ext = ' .jpeg';
  /// missing break here
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
```

So you upload a jpg, and the code continues on into the PNG section, hence your error.

And so, no, it's not a problem with Xamp server... It's a PEBKAC error.

Comment: Thank! Im sitting on it..and I didnt see missing `break;` :(